# Is the 737NG hydraulically controlled or electronically controlled?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing-737, boeing, control-surfaces, hydraulic-system

I know that the 737NG is not fly-by-wire, but are the control surfaces controlled with hydraulic systems that transfer the input from the pilot to the control surfaces via fluid (hydraulics), or is the pilots' input transferred to the control surfaces' electronic actuators via electric signals?

Comment: "*electronic actuators*"... electronics and torque are not good friends :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the B737NG, the pilot stick inputs are transferred to hydraulic actuators, via mechanical (steel) cables. For example for the Power Control Units of the ailerons, as also depicted in [this question:](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46179/21091)

[image]

[The site where the image came from](http://part66school.blogspot.com/2012/12/fly-by-wire.html) also lists a schematic pic for a fly-by-wire setup. There is still a hydraulic actuator but no more steel cable loop to the extremes of the aeroplane, only an electrical or data wire that sends a signal to an electronic controller near the control surface. The controller measures the surface position, subtracts that from the pilot input position, and deflects the hydraulic valve until the actual surface position = required position.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's hydraulic.

Electric actuators or power-by-wire is actually a far more exotic technology than fly-by-wire, and the latter is a hard prerequisite for the former.

Normal fly-by-wire is still based on hydraulic systems, with the electrical FBW system controlling the valves. And even in power-by-wire systems, the final actuator is typically a small enclosed hydraulic unit.

The newer 737 MAX has a couple FBW elements (spoilers), but is still a manual system, well short of FBW or PBW.

Comment: Mhmmm, how bout on the max? And does that mean that the 737 is less reliable than the a320? Or is it safer as a human is operqting the controls?

Comment: By max I meant the 737MAX

Comment: Reliability is a complex subject, and safety a further separate one. Statistically speaking, the A320 has a [better record](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/why-does-the-boeing-737-have-5-x-the-passenger-fatalities-of-the-airbus-320). What can be said for sure is the A320 is a much more modern design - the 737 is itself based on the 707.

Comment: Yes, true, but why is the 737 still so popular? Its the A320 is so good in every aspect, then why does Ryanair use them?

Comment: The economics. The 737 is simpler and lighter, coming out to a slightly lower CASM. But it's got a tighter cabin and can't carry ULD boxes. The two have been close in sales, with A320 [edging out ahead](https://aviationvoice.com/airbus-a320-neo-vs-boeing-737-max-2-201602121522/) lately. You'll have to read a lot of [industry publications](https://airwaysmag.com/best-of-airways/737max-vs-a320neo/) to get an idea of what the competition is about. The short version is of course money.